# Bit Packaging in C

Tags: c

I have gone through the available questions on Stack overflow but I did not find any relevant to my problem. I have image which contains binary data, each pixel I access as a byte but as my image binary I can release the memory using bit packing. But I don't know how to do it and I'm not finding any good sources to learn from.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What format is the image in? Which library are you using to read the Image into memory? Could you post some code you got so far?

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. I am using opencv library to read the image. It is JPEG format.

Comment: What do you mean by that "i can release the memory using bit packing"?

Comment: As its 8 bit in a byte and I am using only 2 bit for 0 and 1 so rest bit is unused so the I can save the memory using bit packing.

Comment: Bit packing might slow down the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what references you found ... Or what the actual problem is.

You can do something like this:

```
typedef enum  { ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE } pix2;

uint8_t pack_values(pix2 p1, pix2 p2, pix2 p3, pix4 p4)
{
  return (p1 << 6) | (p2 << 4) | (p3 << 2) | p4;
}
```

The above will "pack" four two-bit values into a single 8-bit value. Assigning the bits like this (excuse my ASCII graphics skills):

```
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
bit:   |7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
value: | p1| p2| p3| p4|
       +---+---+---+---+
```